# python menu list

Tags: python-3.x

`odd()` prints the odd numbers from 1 to 99 inclusive (10 numbers on a line)

`threes()` prints multiples of 3 from 303 down to 3 (6 numbers on a line)

`listave(list)` returns the average of list

`revstr(str)` returns `str` in reverse order

This is the problem I am working on and I am not sure where I am going wrong with this. I am using the code that I have made from last year and wanted to edit this code to use this string above.

```
    def print_menu():  ## Your menu design here
            print
            30 * "-", "MENU", 30 * "-"
            print
            "1. Menu Option 1"
            print("\n".join(str(i) for i in range(1, 100, 2)))
            "2. Menu Option 2"
            print
            "3. Menu Option 3"
            print
            "4. Menu Option 4"
            print
            "5. Exit"
            print
            67 * "-"


    loop = True

    while loop:  ## While loop which will keep going until loop = False
        print_menu()  ## Displays menu
        choice = input("Enter your choice [1-5]: ")

        if choice == 1:
            print
            "Menu 1 has been selected"
           ## print("\n".join(str(i) for i in range(1, 100, 2)))
        elif choice == 2:
            print
            "Menu 2 has been selected"
            ## You can add your code or functions here
        elif choice == 3:
            print
            "Menu 3 has been selected"
            ## You can add your code or functions here
        elif choice == 4:
            print
            "Menu 4 has been selected"
            ## You can add your code or functions here
        elif choice == 5:
            print
            "Menu 5 has been selected"
            ## You can add your code or functions here
            loop = False  # This will make the while loop to end as not value of loop is set to False
    else:
         # Any integer inputs other than values 1-5 we print an error message
        exit()
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? I don't see a question here.

Comment: sorry about my english its not that great..  english is not my first language

Comment: The problem is you haven't asked a question. What do you need help with? Your post is too broad.

Comment: 87
89
91
93
95
97
99
Enter your choice [1-5]:   this is not the intended output i wanted

Comment: this output intend to have looks like this when i press enter 1

1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 
21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 
41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 
61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 
81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97 99

Answer (score 0):

I think that the idea is that you should implement each of the functions `odd()`, `threes()`, `listave()`, and `revstr()` . Then call them from the code that deals with the menu.

Example for the `odd()` printing function:

```
def odd():
    for i in enumerate(range(1, 100, 2), 1):
        print('{:>2}'.format(n), end=' ')
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print('')

def print_menu():  ## Your menu design here
    print(30 * "-", "MENU", 30 * "-")
    print("1. Menu Option 1")
    print("2. Menu Option 2")
    print("3. Menu Option 3")
    print("4. Menu Option 4")
    print("5. Exit")
    print(67 * "-")

loop = True
while loop:
    print_menu()
    choice = input("Enter your choice [1-5]: ")

    if choice == '1':
        print("Menu 1 has been selected")
        odd()
    elif choice == '2':
        print("Menu 2 has been selected")
        threes()
    ....
    elif choice == '5':
        loop = False
```

Notice that `input()` returns a string, so the conditions need to check for a string, not an integer.